# Present different models grouped using 2 common fields

Tags: django, django-models

My projects uses three Images models. The models are

```
STAGE = [
    ('Initial', 'Initial'),
    ('Observation','Observation'),
    ('Initial', 'Initial')
    ('Progress','Progress'),
    ('Final', 'Final'),
    ('Post treatment','Post treatment'),
]

class Xray(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTime()
    desc = models.CharField(choices=XRAY, max_length=15)
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGE, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(...)


class External(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTime()
    desc = models.CharField(choices=EXTERNAL, max_length=15)
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGE, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(...)

class Internal(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTime()
    desc = models.CharField(choices=INTERNAL, max_length=15)
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGE, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
```

I want to be able to display these three models on my template like so:

```
Date:Stage
    All pictures that have date = Date and stage=Stage
```

How can I group them so I am able to to this? Do you think It would be better if stage was a model by itself and be a foreignkey in every image mode and the date be a field of the stage model?

```
class Internal(models.Model):        
    desc = models.CharField(choices=INTERNAL, max_length=15)
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGE, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(...)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)

class Stage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(choices=STAGE, max_lenght=20) 
    date = models.DateTime()
```

Notice that one picture can only have one date and be at one stage (so maybe better a OneToOne Field?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can model `Image` as a [Concrete Base Class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

```
class Image(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTime()
    stage = models.CharField(choices=STAGE, max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(...)


class Xray(Image):
    desc = models.CharField(choices=XRAY, max_length=15)


....
```

Then you can query all three kinds of `Image` objects using normal syntax like:

```
Image.objects.filter(date=datetime.date(2014, 1, 3), stage='Initial')
```

Comment: how will I group them the way I want then?

Comment: This way creates two different data-tables correct?

Comment: and then i can do Image.desc to get the description of the each Image?

Comment: Sorry about the ninja edits. Yes, there will be separate tables (four in total).

Comment: With all the fields? Can I do image.desc? No worries about edits :)

Comment: No I singled out desc because I thought it needs to be seperated, else you can go with just one object and another field to identify which type is. A solution that I would prefer. But you would know the problem domain better.

Comment: In this example you cannot access `image.desc`. Use `image.xray.desc` instead.

Comment: No desc is different so separate. But this won't solve the problem of trying to present them in a for loop in my template cause I won't know If the Image is xray or internal or external correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47828/discussion-between-arocks-and-apostolos)

Comment: I want to thank arocks for his time and effort. Thank you again!